# imagej always shows black images

Tags: java, imagej

for an assignment I have to display an image using imagej in java. So I used the following code:

```
    FloatProcessor abc=new FloatProcessor(imageSizeX,imageSizeY);
        for (int i=0;i<imageSizeX;i++){
              for(int j=0;j<imageSizeY;j++){
              abc.putPixel(i, j, 100);
              }
        }
        ImagePlus im=new ImagePlus("test",abc);
        im.show();
```

but the Image I get is always completely black. Can you tell me what the mistake is?
It should at least be white if the value was 0 shouldn't it?
(FYI: imageSizeX=imageSizeY=256)

Comment: Looking at the [FloatProcessor.putPixel()](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#putPixel-int-int-int-) API: _"For float images, 'value' is expected to be a float converted to an int using Float.floatToIntBits()."_  I'm not sure what float value it's expecting, but you could try `Float.floatToIntBits(1.0)` or similar

Answer (score 0):

`.putPixel` uses the conversion `Float.intBitsToFloat`.

If you want a direct access to the pixels, you can use `setf(int x, int y, float value)`.

Moreover, if you already have the pixels into an array, you can use the constructors to immediately set the pixel values `FloatProcessor(int width, int height, int[] pixels)`.